# If I shadow a buit-in function, how can I recover it?

Tags: scheme, racket

Take this example:

```
(define sqrt (lambda (x) (* 2 (sqrt x))))
(sqrt 2)
2.828427 ...
```

How can I call the original built-in `sqrt` procedure without restarting my interpreter (or undefine the shadowing define)?

Actually, what happens internally when we do this? Does the built-in get overwritten, or do two procedures coexist in different namespaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of `sqrt` will actually cause a stack overflow, because it recurses into itself, not the built-in `sqrt`. :-P

Anyway, in Racket, your definition of `sqrt` will affect your current module only. It is possible to reimport the built-in `sqrt` under a different name, and call that from your module-specific `sqrt`:

```
(require (rename-in racket/base [sqrt racket-sqrt]))
(define sqrt (lambda (x) (* 2 (racket-sqrt x))))
```

Note that your code won't affect other modules that don't import your module's `sqrt` definition; they will continue to use the built-in `sqrt`.

Comment: At least in Racket 6.5 I don't see any stack overflow. I can call my `sqrt` and it gives me `2*racket_sqrt`, i.e., it does not recurse into itself. That's what I don't understand. `(sqrt 10000) => 200`.

Comment: @DanielG you are defining `sqrt` it in the interaction window. If you do it in the definition window, it will cause a stack overflow.

Comment: Ok, I see. It does cause a stack overflow if I type it in the definition window. But why not on the interaction window?

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug? But one thing I know for sure is that the interaction window has its own rules. For example, you can `define` the same id several times. Writing `(define (foo) bar)` won't cause an unbound id error, while it would cause one in the definition window (this is to let you write `(define bar 123)` later).

Comment: I should point out that this is not a stack overflow, because Racket does not use the machine's stack. It just simply runs out of memory.

Comment: @LeifAndersen Ah, dynamically allocated call frames. I like. (I've always considered that a much more ideal way to implement continuations, as opposed to, say, stack copying.)

Comment: The reason the behavior is different in the interactions window is because [the top level is hopeless](https://gist.github.com/samth/3083053).

Comment: At the top level the last `sqrt` in `(define sqrt (lambda (x) (* 2 (sqrt x))))` refers not to the sqrt being defined but to the previous definition (the builtin sqrt). In a module it will refer to "itself" - since in a module the definition `(define sqrt ...)` will give `sqrt` the entire module as its scope.

It might look inconsistent but the choice was made to make the repl nicer to use.